# Error connecting to LDAP with @ (at-sign) in password

Tags: java, java-8, ldap

I'm trying to connect to LDAP server. But when I use principal with password which begins with "@" sign, I get an error: 
`[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090404, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1772 ]`

Using other password, without "@" sign, works just fine.

```
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=User Name,OU=Something,OU=Other,DC=example,DC=com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "@password");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://192.168.168.10:3268");
LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
```

Comment: May be percent-encoding can help: try `%40password` instead of `@password`

Comment: @Eritrean not helping.